# Azure NetworkSecurityGroup rule for WebApp

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-application-gateway, network-security

I want to enable traffic from my webapp (that sits inside the VNET and has its private IP) to Application Gateway (that is deployed to the same VNET and has NSG attached to its subnet).

How can I do it?

If I add webapp outbound ip to NSG as allowed - traffic works fine, but I do not want to hardcode this ip.

If I add "Internet" service tag it works as well, but it is too broad for my taste.

I could not find any other relevant service tags for me (tried "AppServiceManager", "AppService" and "AppService.AustraliaEast").
Also checked this [document](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519) (and had to update the filename to last Monday! :) ) but could not find the IP that worked for me (`52.187.231.76`).

Ideal solution would be to allow only VNET traffic, but this did not do the trick as well... All ServiceEndpoints are there.

Answer (score 1):

Checked with Azure support. Unfortunately there is no service tags available to do this yet.

Workaround - to manually add security rules for each application that supposed to access Application Gateway to allow **Outbound IPs**.

To do so - go to azure portal, to the application that needs to be able to access App GW. Go to properties blade and copy `Outbound IP addresses`. Then go to NSG and create a new inbound security rule to allow access from all of those IPs (at least it can be 1 rule).

According to Azure support those IPs should not change unless you recreate the whole webapp and the app can only cycle through those IPs.